# What is htc file that we are using for border radius

Tags: css

Last time some one suggested me that htc file for border radius for IE. I Used that, its working fine. But I don't know what is the use of that? can anybody briefly explain about htc

Answer (score 0):

it's for css3 support for internet explorer 8 and earlier

you can get all the info you want [here](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/)